# How to set default value for 'managed_file' type in drupal8

Tags: php, drupal

In drupal 8,I create a custom form to upload a .xlsx file.  The file is saved successfully When I upload a .xlsx file, but I forget the file name when I access the page next time. So I want to display a default value to the element. These are my code, But it is not effective. Pls advise, thank u.

```
$form['test_file'] = [
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => $this->t('Test File'),
  '#upload_location' => 'private://',
  '#upload_validators' => [
    'file_validate_extensions' => ['xls xlsx'],
  ],
  '#description' => $this->t('Please upload test data excel file.'),
  '#default_value' => $config->get('test_file'),
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$element[#value][fids] is the condition used during the process of the managed_file field.
( see core/module/file/src/Element/ManagedFile.php )
try this :

```
$fid = $config->get('test_file'); // the fid of the file you want to show in the field
$form['test_file'] = [
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => $this->t('Test File'),
  '#upload_location' => 'private://',
  '#upload_validators' => [
    'file_validate_extensions' => ['xls xlsx'],
  ],
  '#description' => $this->t('Please upload test data excel file.'),
  '#default_value' => null, // don't need
];
// A condition for your test_file variable
if($fid != NULL){
  $form['test_file']['#value']['fids'] = array($fid);
}
```